# Stuck with getting rows based on three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get rows that may have at least one row in second table but it can not be in third table to be included in result.

This is what I achieved but it seems to not return correct values(I want values that have no rows in logs table, if logs contains row with `networks.id` then I do not want to include this row but if `networks.id` is in `network_sessions` table and not in logs then I want to count it):

```
  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(n.id) as networks_count FROM networks as n
    LEFT JOIN network_sessions AS ns ON ns.network_id = n.id
    LEFT JOIN logs AS l ON l.network_session_id = ns.id
    WHERE n.status = "LIVE" AND n.updated_at BETWEEN "2020-07-01 00:00:00" AND "2020-07-31 00:00:59"
    GROUP BY n.id
    HAVING COUNT(l.id) = 0; /* Is this line even needed? */
```

In this case I want to get result 1(count). I want the query to return only network with id 1 Because network 2 has session but it is also in logs and if it is also in logs I do not want to include it in my query.

```
NETWORKS
id       1
id       2

NETWORK_SESSIONS(has log_id which links to logs)
network_id      1, log_id 0
network_id      2, log_id 1

LOGS
1. network_session_id  2
```

Actually I also need the query where there are more than one log for network. But I can do it if I get working version SQL of previously described issue.

Am I on the right track? I must say I am not confident at all in SQL. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: can you provide, create table and insert sample data scripts for the query you mentioned ?

Comment: Group By is distinct - Use group by OR distinct but not both together.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks for the information, I indeed did not know that.

Comment: *if logs contains row with networks.id then I do not want to include this row* is there a direct relation between networks and logs?

Comment: @forpas unfortunately there is no direct connection

Comment: Fine, then the relation passes through `network_sessions`. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the join to `network_sessions` to an `INNER` join:

```
SELECT n.id 
FROM networks as n
INNER JOIN network_sessions AS ns ON ns.network_id = n.id
LEFT JOIN logs AS l ON l.network_session_id = ns.id
WHERE n.status = 'LIVE' AND n.updated_at BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 00:00:59'
GROUP BY n.id
HAVING COUNT(l.id) = 0;
```

Or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.id 
FROM networks as n
INNER JOIN network_sessions AS ns ON ns.network_id = n.id
LEFT JOIN logs AS l ON l.network_session_id = ns.id
WHERE n.status = 'LIVE' AND n.updated_at BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 00:00:59'
AND l.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does return only one row with some weird ID which is not in date range not in logs tabe and the id is too big to be network id. All this if I remove the COUNT around the DISTINCT

Comment: This query does not return any ids. It returns only 1 integer number which is the counter of rows.

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp see my 2nd query.

Comment: Can you tell me what does the first query returns, why it only returns 1 row? Although second query seems to work properly. I am still confused  what is difference between the GROUP BY vs second query?

Comment: In your code you use COUNT(), so I thought that you only want to count the ids. Now I changed the 1st query also.

Comment: I did try the first one which returns one row with number 2732 which is bigger than the number I have networks.. So it can not be either network id nor the count of the networks.

Comment: Then you will have to post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: I did edit my question with simple table and what the result would be.

Comment: Isn't there another column in network_sessions to link to logs?

Comment: Sorry, there is

Comment: Check this demo of the 1st query: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=73ed90f9b2008a0a8e55480e30645d19 I removed the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide create table scripts with insert scripts of sample data or set up a dbfiddle to get accurate answers, probably the below query what you need, you should use `not exists` to do it.

```
 SELECT 
        DISTINCT COUNT(n.id) as networks_count 
        FROM network  n
        LEFT JOIN network_sessions  ns ON ns.network_id = n.id
        and n.status = "LIVE" AND n.updated_at BETWEEN "2020-07-01 00:00:00" AND "2020-07-31 00:00:59"
        WHERE not exists (select 1 from logs  where logs.network_session_id = ns.id);
```

Comment: For me it seems like it also includes the netowrk_sessions rows not just network in the result.

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
SELECT COUNT(n.id) as networks_count 
FROM networks as n
LEFT JOIN network_sessions AS ns ON ns.network_id = n.id
WHERE n.status = "LIVE" 
 AND (n.updated_at BETWEEN "2020-07-01 00:00:00" AND "2020-07-31 00:00:59" )
 AND  n.id not in ( select logs.network_session_id from logs) 
GROUP BY n.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

get id from logs table

```
select distinct id from logs
```

get id from network_sessions where id not in above

```
select distinct id from network_sessions where id not in (select distinct id from logs)
```

then count id in networks

```
select count(id) from networks where id in(select distinct id from network_sessions where id not in (select distinct id from logs))
```